# Hide Navigation Bar on MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a MasterDetailPage that contains the following constructor:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<JobsPage>(this, "OpenMenu", (sender) => {
            IsPresented = true;
        });

        MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
        this.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
        App.NavPage = new NavigationPage(new JobsPage() { Title = "Jobs" });
        Detail = App.NavPage;
    }
```

As you can see, I've set `SetHasNavigationBar` and `SetHasBackButton` to false.

On a *different* page (a ContentPage, not a MasterDetailPage), I did the same thing in the constructor:

```
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
    InitializeComponent();
```

On my `ContentPage`, this works fine, as shown below.

[image]

On my `MasterDetailPage`, however, I'm still seeing the Navigation bar.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how is structured your navigation, but try this:

```
public MainPage()
{

        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<JobsPage>(this, "OpenMenu", (sender) => {
            IsPresented = true;
        });

        MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
        this.MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

        var navPage = new NavigationPage(new JobsPage() { Title = "Jobs" });
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(navPage, false);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(navPage, false);

        App.NavPage = navPage;
        Detail = App.NavPage;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this with no luck. I believe this may be a bug in Xamarin. See https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89871/uwp-mysterious-command-bar

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a Master-DetailPage does not support Navigation Bars. It is the root container where you can place your content pages. These pages can now contain a navigation bar that can redirect you to the root page in the Master-DetailPage.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and i had a work-around for this.

Set the Detail twice.

```
// 1st time
var jobPage = new JobsPage() { Title = "Jobs" };
Detail = jobPage;

// 2nd time
var navPage = new NavigationPage(jobPage, false);
Detail = navPage;
```

Set the 1st in constructor and 2nd in OnAppearing.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting those lines in detail page of the MasterDetailPage

**In code behind**

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

**In xaml**

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```