# Xamarin Forms - Hide navigation bar in MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

**I need hide navigation bar in xamarin forms 3.0**.

I try this, but dont work:
[Hide Navigation Bar on MasterDetailPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157197/hide-navigation-bar-on-masterdetailpage)

I want hide navigation bar for create a custom bar, **also I need a way to open menu**.
Thanks.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
...
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public List<MasterPageItem> menuList { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();

        menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "home.png", TargetType = typeof(HomePage) });
        menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Settings", Icon = "setting.png", TargetType = typeof(SettingsPage) });
        menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Help", Icon = "help.png", TargetType = typeof(HelpPage) });

        navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;

        var navPage = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HomePage)));

        //I try this:
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(navPage, false);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(navPage, false);

        Detail = navPage;
    }
...
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App3"
             x:Class="App3.MainPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Spacing="15">
                   ...
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>

        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Source repo:
https://github.com/uiahhh/stackoverflow/tree/master/HideNavBar

I want remove this navbar in red circle:
[image]

Comment: You should put relevant code in your question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I put the code and screen. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the ***detail*** page you have to remove the navigation bar with `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` in the constructor right after `InitializeComponent()`

```
public partial class MyPage : NavigationPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Pedro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51140684/11809808), you can also hide the navigation bar in your `.xaml` file. For example:

```xml
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:** This works in Xamarin 4.0 but I haven't tested it in 3.0.