# How To: Hide Page NavigationBar in Prism/Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm creating a simple SpringBoard page that does not need to display the navigation bar.  Who do you hide it?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: [Xamarin Forms - Hide navigation bar in MasterDetailPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137298/xamarin-forms-hide-navigation-bar-in-masterdetailpage)

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        **NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);**

    }
}
```