# Xamarin forms - How to disable MasterDetailPage menu button

Tags: c#, button, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I would to disable the top left button of the Main Menu when the `busy indicator` is shown.

I already found the point where I can make this edit, but I haven't find how to disable this button.

Anyone can help me please? :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "disable" I'm assuming you mean get rid of the Navigation bar, which contains the menu icon completely? If so, I use this code when I set the IsBusy property to true:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Then when it's no longer busy just set it to true for it to reappear

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
```

Comment: In Xamarin 3.0 this line should be put to detail page constructor. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137298/xamarin-forms-hide-navigation-bar-in-masterdetailpage?rq=1